# cx_freeze "no module named" error when converting .py to .exe

Tags: python, python-3.6, cx-freeze

I'm trying to convert .py file to .exe using `cx_freeze` and I get no errors while it's building. I tried it with another .py file and it worked perfectly, but this time, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "borzacommercial.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bcrypt\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from bcrypt import _bcrypt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can we see your setup script?

Comment: `from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None


executables = [Executable("borzacommercial.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
    },

}

setup(
    name = "<any name>",
    options = options,
    version = "<any number>",
    description = '<any description>',
    executables = executables
)`

Comment: Try including `_cffi_backend` in packages

Comment: thank you, i imported it in the .py file and it works now.

Comment: I'll make an answer that you might decide to accept then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a message saying that part of a package is missing the first thing to do is to try adding the name of the missing package.  You may get further errors which say that further modules are missing but just include those as well.  You can do this by simply adding the name of the package in the `packages` option.  Like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

base = None executables = [Executable("borzacommercial.py", base=base)] 

packages = ["idna", "_cffi_backend"] 
options = { 'build_exe': { 'packages':packages, }, } 

setup( name = "<any name>", options = options, version = "<any number>", 
description = '<any description>', executables = executables )
```

Answer (score 1):

importing _cffi_backend solved this issue